# Как вывести из ассоциативного массива число с плавающей точкой

Tags: php, массивы, изображения, echo

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents ('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1');
$json = json_decode($content, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);

foreach( $json['weather'] as $arr) {
    $weather = $arr['main'];
}
foreach ($json['main'] as $varray) {
    $temp = $varray['temp'];
}

echo "<h1>Город: $json[name]</br>Погода: $weather<br>Температура: $temp</h1>";
```

Не получается вывести значение $temp, т.к. оно является числом с плавающей точкой. Как его в итоге можно вывести? И вообще правильно ли это выводить так из массива данные?

+хотелось бы в этом же документе выводить картинку в зависимости от погоды, как организовать вывод картинки (допустим, локально расположенной)?

Comment: $json['main'] это не массив массивов, а обычный ассоциативный массив, получайте так $temp = $json['main']['temp']; без foreach

Comment: Спасибо, остался вопрос с картинкой) Что то гугл особо не помогает.

Comment: ну например по переменной "light intensity drizzle" - если это значение выведите картинку солнца с одной каплей, будет другое значение - выведите соответствующую картинку. делов то на пук-пук.

Comment: Я о том, какой командой можно выаести. А так все верно вывел с условием if $weather == Drizzle. А саму картинку echo '<img src="путь">' не знал просто что данная конструкция работает.